# alignment of color bar labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, alignment, label, colorbar

I have a horizontal color map that spans the whole canvas with labels at either end showing the minimum and maximum values. The problem is that for different min and max values, the labels stick more outwards, changing the overall size of the image, which is something I don't want.

I wanted to align the label on the left (-40000 in the image) to the left and the one on the right (40000 in the image) to the right to solve this problem but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

So my question in short is, how do I change the alignment of the labels in a color bar?
[image]

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: https://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg07447.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# some random data to plot
x = np.random.rand(10,10)*80e3 - 40e3
plt.imshow(x, aspect='auto', vmin=-40e3, vmax=40e3)

# create the colorbar
cb = plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal', ticks=[-40e3,0,40e3])

# get the xtick labels
tl = cb.ax.get_xticklabels()

# set the alignment for the first and the last
tl[0].set_horizontalalignment('left')
tl[-1].set_horizontalalignment('right')

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]